# Error when trying to connect to H2 database

Tags: java, connection, h2

Did any of you had this below error when trying to connect to H2?
The release I'm using is 1.4.199, on windows, with TAFJFuctions.

First I run this command:
`java -server -cp h2-1.4.199.jar;C:\Users\...\H2\TAFJFunctions.jar org.h2.tools.Server -web -tcp -tcpPort 9092 -tcpAllowOthers -baseDir C:\Users\...\H2\bin`

and I've got connected with TCP server running  and Web Console server running as well.
Then I've run this command:
`SET H2URL=jdbc:h2:tcp://locaLhost/t24db;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=0;FILE_LOCK=NO;IFEXISTS=TRUE;CACHE_SIZE=8192;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000`

And then this command:
`java -server -cp h2-1.4.199.jar;C:\Users\...\H2\TAFJFunctions.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url %H2URL% -driver org.h2.Driver -user t24 -password t24`

And here I've got the below error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database "C:/Users/.../H2/bin/t24db" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it [90146-199]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:67)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:160)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:617)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:607)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:143)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:431)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:317)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.h2.tools.Shell.runTool(Shell.java:148)
    at org.h2.tools.Shell.main(Shell.java:81)"
```

Any idea how to get this working?

Thank you,
Carina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `IFEXISTS=TRUE` the problem is oblivious, but without this parameter or with attempt to set it to `FALSE` situation is not going to be changed.

All recent versions of H2 database don't allow remote (including local TCP connections) database creation by default any more due to security reasons. When it is allowed, everyone who can connect to your port can create a new database, get ADMIN privileges in it and therefore get the same access to your system as your JVM and your user account allows.

Unfortunately, H2 1.4.199 throws a confusing error message, it was improved only in 1.4.200 and in this version (when `IFEXISTS=TRUE` wasn't used) the error message is “Database … not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments)”.

If you use a TCP (or Pg/ODBC) server you need to create your databases in some other way before you try to connect to them with networked protocol.

For example, you can open the JDBC connection (`DriverManager.getConnection()`) with embedded URL and close it immediately.

You can replace `org.h2.tools.Server` with `org.h2.tools.Console` and you'll see another http connection URL (if you start it from the command line), something like `http://127.0.0.2:8082?key=12c58e1c5f9ce1ae88a2921f74e7655ed91a80746730cc6bfa8d4bbb464f69ee`; with this URL you will be able to create the database from the web interface (only if remove web interface is not enabled).

You can also add the `-tool` parameter (only to `Console`, the `Server` doesn't support it) to get H2 Console icon in the system tray, its context menu has a command to create a new database and this icon can also open the web interface with the same security key. Don't share this key with anyone. It will be different on each restart, however.

You can also use the command-line Shell tool.

https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#creating_new_databases

In the worst case you can enable the remove database creation, but it is not really secure even with local connections and it is completely insecure when remote connections are enabled as in your case. You will have a well-known remote security hole in your system, I don't think that it is your intention.

Comment: I've tried with the command-line to create a new db and I'm getting the same error:

Welcome to H2 Shell 1.4.199 (2019-03-13)
[Enter]   jdbc:h2:~/test
URL       C:/Users/C64075/H2/bin/test
Driver    org.h2.Driver
[Enter]
User      sa
Password
SQL Exception: Driver org.h2.Driver is not suitable for C:/Users/C64075/H2/bin/test;IFEXISTS=TRUE
[Enter]   jdbc:h2:~/test
URL       C:/Users/C64075/H2/bin/t24db
Driver    org.h2.Driver
[Enter]
User      t24
Password
SQL Exception: Driver org.h2.Driver is not suitable for C:/Users/C64075/H2/bin/t24db;IFEXISTS=TRUE
[Enter]   jdbc:h2:~/test

Comment: I've also tried the Console instead of tool parameter and I'm getting this:
Hmmm...can’t reach this page
Try this
• Make sure you’ve got the right web address: http://10.29.35.177:8082
• Search for "http://10.29.35.177:8082" on Bing
• Refresh the page
Details 
• Report this issue

Comment: If you use a command-line tool, you should specify `jdbc:h2:/path/to/t24db` as URL, where `/path/to/t24db` is an absolute or relative path to the database (without file name extension). You can't use only the path without `jdbc:h2:` prefix as JDBC URL.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with the version 1.4.200 and I managed to connect. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no database called t24db already.

In the property spring.datasource.url property which you use to connect to h2, remove the parameter IFEXISTS=TRUE.
This will ensure that the database is created if it does not exist.

Comment: Hi Midhun, I've removed the parameter and closed the windows of the cmd , reopened and re-run the commands without that parameter and I'm getting the same error. :(

Comment: Try setting it to false instead of removing

Comment: I've did a restart and set it to FALSE, but it's the same :(

Comment: ok: Web Console server running at http://10.29.35.177:8082 (only local connections)